# Placed order showing test Shipping and Billing Address

Tags: magento2

Everything is working fine in the checkout. When an order is placed, instead of the customer Shipping and Billing Address, the order details show the test information instead of customers.

[image]

Appreciate feedback. Thank

Comment: Additionally, the Payment Information appears to be static, as  this specific address was placed using a credit card, but it shows check/money order